# Rating() is not public in 'android.media.Rating.' Cannot be assessed from outside package

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onPositiveButtonClicked(int value, @NotNull String comments) {
    Rating rating = new Rating(String.valueOf(value), comments);
}
```

I have a red color word Rating. It tells me:

> Rating() is not public in `android.media.Rating.' Cannot be assessed from outside package in onPositiveButtonClicked method.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Rating), you don't instantiate it directly. Instead, you use one of the following static methods:

```
Rating.newPercentageRating(float percent);

Rating.newStarRating(int starRatingStyle, float starRating);

Rating.newThumbRating(boolean thumbIsUp);

Rating.newUnratedRating(int ratingStyle);
```

None of these match what you're doing, and I have no idea what you're trying to do. `value` is the index of the button that was clicked (ie the positive button), and `comments` is something else. Neither applies to Rating.